# Integrate DTCoreText with xcode project

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I wanted to convert from html to NSAttributedString, and i found away solving this using DTCoreText here https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText

i followed the instruction but still getting errors, any help for how to integrate it with an existing xcode project

my xcode version is 4.3.2

and the project is uploaded here: http://www.mediafire.com/?0o281nv3d04s5sx

and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the errors you get, please?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageSourceUpdateData", referenced from:
      -[DTLazyImageView createAndShowProgressiveImage] in libDTCoreText.a(DTLazyImageView.o).

I tried to solve this by adding this file "DTLazyImageView.m" to the files to be compiled (compile sources) from the build phases, but i get another error ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_DTLazyImageView._connection in /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DTCoreTes ...

Comment: did you include the CoreGraphics.framework in your project?

Comment: I can send you the source project if you want to see it

Comment: Ok thanks, here is the link,

http://www.mediafire.com/?0o281nv3d04s5sx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your problem. The framework ImageIO.framework is missing from your target. Just add it (by selecting your target, 'build phases' -> 'link binary with libraries' -> '+' button).

Comment: here is what i get:

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_DTLazyImageView._connection in /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DTCoreTest6-daqfodxikdhmrwcwluwfbdtqwknq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libDTCoreText.a(DTLazyImageView.o) and /Users/macuser/Desktop/iOS Test Projects/DTTest9/DerivedData/DTTest9/Build/Intermediates/DTTest9.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DTTest9.build/Objects-normal/i386/DTLazyImageView.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot, you also have libDTCoreText.a to remove as you have the source code of this library.

Comment: Thank you Niko very much, you really helped me. But i have a problem when trying to call "initWithHtml" method in NSAttributedString, it raise an exception with un recognized selector, The compiler sees the method, but it is not seen during run time

note: i imported NSAttributedString+html

Comment: could you update your project and send it me back, i'll have a look if you want

Comment: Sorry for being late, here is the link for the updated project

http://www.mediafire.com/?kjbo4w7259ebg9v

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, the problem is that you do not compile the source code DTCoreText, if you have a look in 'Build Phases' -> 'Compile Sources', only a few files are compiled. I tried to add all files from DTCoreText, but for the moment, I'm not able to compile it, I have some issues, like : "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_default_css", referenced from:
      +[DTCSSStylesheet defaultStyleSheet] in DTCSSStylesheet.o
  "_default_css_len", referenced from:
      +[DTCSSStylesheet defaultStyleSheet] in DTCSSStylesheet.o
"

Comment: I downloaded the DTCoreText xcode project. It seems we are missing some data created by some script that is launched at compilation. Have you read the file Readme.markdown, it seems to explain how to add its project inside an other project?